# Does もらう express gratitude?

Tags: giving-and-receiving

I've come across the following:

> ### もらう (morau)
>
> This is the last word we’re going to review. もらう (morau) means to receive or to get. This word has a nuance that you’re feeling grateful of what you’ve received. So you cannot use it for something that have negative nuance or about something that you don’t feel grateful about.

<sub>Recovered from [crunchynihongo.com](http://crunchynihongo.com/ageru-kureru-morau-difference/)</sub>

Is this true? I can't find a reputable source which states the above. My book doesn't seem to mention this "nuance".

Comment: A correct answer has already been given so I will say it here.  This must be one of the widespread misconceptions in the world of Japanese-as-a-foreign-language because I hear about it a couple of times every year.  Native speakers do say 「パンチをもらう」、「小言をもらう」, etc.  To give a more timely example, we even say this: https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E2%80%9D%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%8A%E3%82%92%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86%E2%80%9D&x=wrt&aq=-1&ai=f4ddf480-0fc5-4434-9388-badd6eb3c701&ts=60058&ei=UTF-8&fr=top_ga1_sa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is true.

We do use "もらう" when we received something unwanted.

Like *変なモノもらっちゃった(I received something weird.)*, or (a little bit tricky use) *風邪もらってきちゃったみたい(I think I've caught a cold.)*.

It's either the author of this article has misunderstood something, or he/she doesn't fully understand the language.

Comment: Is the same true with verb-てもらう?

Comment: @user3856370 Since "-てもらう" is a word that does not have any negative nuance(afaik), such as **し**てもらう, **させ**てもらう, or **やっ**てもらう. I think it's possible to have such nuance in a sarcastic way, but other than sarcasm, I think it has only positive nuance.  Perhaps this is the reason for article writer to misunderstanding the word "もらう".